# My project gradle properties are not being read on Expo eas android build and it gives me error

Tags: android, react-native, expo, release, eas

**When building using the expo eas build for my app it gives me an error on the 'Run Gradlew' step.**

`eas build --profile release -p android`

As far as I have been able to observe it is because it does not recognise the gradle.properties file and asks me to configure elements that are already defined there.

In local everything works perfectly.

[Run Gradlew error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/72r82.png)

```
> Task :react-native-gradle-plugin:compileJava NO-SOURCE
> Task :react-native-gradle-plugin:classes
> Task :react-native-gradle-plugin:inspectClassesForKotlinIC
> Task :react-native-gradle-plugin:jar
[stderr] 
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
[stderr] 
* Where:
[stderr] 
Build file '/home/expo/workingdir/build/android/app/build.gradle' line: 309
[stderr] 
* What went wrong:
[stderr] 
A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
[stderr] 
> Could not get unknown property 'FLIPPER_VERSION' for object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.
[stderr] 
* Try:
[stderr] 
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
[stderr] 
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
[stderr] 
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
[stderr] 
* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
[stderr] 
BUILD FAILED in 1m 37s
5 actionable tasks: 5 executed
Error: Gradle build failed with unknown error. See logs for the "Run gradlew" phase for more information.
```

[gradle.properties on my project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z6ruV.png)

I have tried using the option to sync the gradle.properties with android studio and the result is that the error persists.

My expo SDK version: 47

My build.gradle...
[android/build.gradle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tdhtY.png)

I have tried re building in local

I have tried updating any library

I have tried running expo doctor.

Nothing works. Expo still gives me error in the 'Run Gradlew' step when building.